# HTML5 localstorage: store and download file

Tags: html, local-storage

How can I use HTML5 local storage to save a little exe file and then download it by clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Localstorage` as you think is not a DataBase or even the File System, it's just some plain `JSON` files that store tiny bits of data in `key: value` pairs.

If you have worked with JSON before this will be very easy to grasp the Idea behind it.

Below is an example of setting and retrieving values from `Local-storage`:

```
locastorage.setItem('KEY',JSON.stringify('VALUE'));
// KEY is kind of like the variable name and the VALUE is the actual Data

JSON.parse(locastorage.getItem('KEY'));
// You use the KEY to access the value

// Using JSON methods stringify and parse just to be on the safer side.
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Localstorage is not for files.

Have a look at Mozilla's documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Instead it's for key/value pairs.

```
// Save data to the current local store
localStorage.setItem("username", "John");

// Access some stored data
alert( "username = " + localStorage.getItem("username"));
```

To start a download, you may want to look at a question like [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: But what about this link:  
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/
It says that you actually can save any file as blob.

Comment: why would you want to do that? and just to be clear, those files are not accessible to the user - they are stored by the browser in a database file.